# What's wrong with this Ruby Mechanize login to stackoverflow script?

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

What is wrong with this? This gets me past the first login page (I think), but I appear to remain logged out.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

#create agent
agent = Mechanize.new { |agent| 
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari 4'
}
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
page = agent.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")

#get login form
login_form = page.form_with(:action => "/users/login")

login_form.openid_username = "username"
login_form.openid_identifier = "password"
page = agent.submit(login_form)
#pp page
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'mechanize'

Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  agent.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")
  agent.page.forms.last do |f|
    f.email = "username"
    f.password = "password"
    f.submit
  end
end
```

This works if you want to login with username/password.

Comment: Does it? agent.page.uri.to_s == https://stackoverflow.com/users/login which is the same result I get from the orig code.

Comment: Do you have a valid username/password to login for testing? Try to use `agent.get(some_new_uri)` to see if it works.